# Path in the PYTHONPATH not in django path

Tags: python, django, import, module, pythonpath

I am writing a web based app based on python and django. I have a source code folder containing `LIBS` directory that has a file named `utils.py`. When I want to install my app a new line is added to `~/.profile` file like `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/test/src/LIBS` (The path is added based on the installation path).

When I run the below code in the interpreter the path is OK:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/home/test/src/LIBS', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

Unfortunately, when i want to load the home page of my app the line that imports `utils` raises an exception

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `~/.profile` only adds the dir to the `PYTHONPATH` in the current shell environment. It's not globally available. When django loads, it uses the `wsgi.py` and another project path.

The easiest way to add a globally available path is to add a .pth file. It should be in your python dist-packages directory (depends on the OS):

```
$ sudo nano /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
/home/test/src/LIBS
```

And save the file.

Now the app will be available for all python instances on your machine.

If you want to add this path only to a specific django project, in the `wsgi.py` add:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/test/src/LIBS")
```