# Python click project, "Django is not available on the PYTHONPATH " error

Tags: django, python-3.x, static-analysis, pylint, python-click

I am having a `click` project which don't use/need Django anywhere but while running `prospector` as part of static analysis throws this strange error

***Command***

```
prospector -I __init__.py --strictness veryhigh --max-line-length 120 src/
```

***Error***

```
Line: 1
    pylint: django-not-available / Django is not available on the PYTHONPATH
```

There was no reference of django anywhere in the project/code . I am fairly new to python, Am i missing something obivious here ?

**python-version : 3.7**

**pip list**

```
apipkg                 1.5
asn1crypto             1.2.0
astroid                2.3.2
atomicwrites           1.3.0
attrs                  19.3.0
auger-python           0.1.35
bitmath                1.3.3.1
boto3                  1.10.14
botocore               1.13.14
bravado                9.2.0
bravado-core           4.9.1
certifi                2019.9.11
cffi                   1.13.2
chardet                3.0.4
click                  6.7
colorama               0.4.1
coloredlogs            10.0
coverage               4.5.4
cryptography           2.3.1
deb-pkg-tools          4.5
docutils               0.15.2
dodgy                  0.1.9
entrypoints            0.3
execnet                1.7.1
executor               21.3
fasteners              0.15
filelock               3.0.12
flake8                 3.7.9
flake8-polyfill        1.0.2
funcsigs               1.0.2
future                 0.18.2
humanfriendly          4.18
hvac                   0.7.1
idna                   2.5
importlib-metadata     0.23
isort                  4.3.21
jmespath               0.9.4
jsonpointer            2.0
jsonschema             3.1.1
lazy-object-proxy      1.4.3
mando                  0.6.4
mccabe                 0.6.1
mock                   3.0.5
monotonic              1.5
more-itertools         7.2.0
murl                   0.5.1
packaging              19.2
pep8                   1.7.1
pep8-naming            0.4.1
pip                    19.3.1
pluggy                 0.13.0
property-manager       2.3.1
prospector             1.1.7
py                     1.8.0
pycodestyle            2.5.0
pycparser              2.19
pydocstyle             4.0.1
pyflakes               2.1.1
pylint                 2.4.3
pylint-celery          0.3
pylint-django          2.0.10
pylint-flask           0.6
pylint-plugin-utils    0.6
pyparsing              2.4.4
pyrsistent             0.15.5
pytest                 5.2.2
pytest-cache           1.0
pytest-cov             2.8.1
pytest-pep8            1.0.6
python-dateutil        2.6.1
python-debian          0.1.33
python-memcached       1.59
pytz                   2019.3
PyYAML                 5.1.2
radon                  4.0.0
raven                  6.9.0
requests               2.19.1
requirements-detector  0.6
rfc3987                1.3.8
customcli              0.1.dev27+g2b07461.d20191114
s3transfer             0.2.1
setoptconf             0.2.0
setuptools             41.6.0
simplejson             3.16.0
six                    1.12.0
snowballstemmer        2.0.0
strict-rfc3339         0.7
swagger-spec-validator 2.4.3
toml                   0.10.0
tox                    3.14.0
tryagain               1.0
typed-ast              1.4.0
urllib3                1.23
verboselogs            1.7
virtualenv             16.7.7
wcwidth                0.1.7
webcolors              1.10
wheel                  0.33.6
wrapt                  1.11.2
zipp                   0.6.0
```

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548720/path-in-the-pythonpath-not-in-django-path

Comment: @Epikstar the think is I don't think prospector should search for django at all here, it install `pylint-django` which declare  `django` only as [extra](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django/blob/v2.0.10/setup.py#L24). I reproduce the error by just installing prospector 1.1.7 and trying to run it against a dummy code. And `pylint` and `pylint-django` themselves run without django installed. So it seems like a bug in prospector to me, it seems to check for `django` even if you didn't declare it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comments I think there is a bug with prospector and [requirement-detector](https://github.com/landscapeio/requirements-detector).

I was able to reproduce the problem by just installing prospector 1.1.7 in an empty virtualenv:

```
$ pip freeze
astroid==2.2.5
dodgy==0.1.9
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
pep8-naming==0.4.1
prospector==1.1.7
pycodestyle==2.3.1
pydocstyle==4.0.1
pyflakes==1.6.0
pylint==2.3.1
pylint-celery==0.3
pylint-django==2.0.10
pylint-flask==0.6
pylint-plugin-utils==0.6
PyYAML==5.1.2
requirements-detector==0.6
setoptconf==0.2.0
six==1.13.0
snowballstemmer==2.0.0
typed-ast==1.4.0
wrapt==1.11.2
```

Then creating a dummy code:

```
$ cat src/__init__.py 

print('something')
```

When running prospector I got the same error:

```
$ prospector src/
/home/sma/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/58918408_so/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pycodestyle.py:113: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
  EXTRANEOUS_WHITESPACE_REGEX = re.compile(r'[[({] | []}),;:]')
Messages
========

src/__init__.py
  Line: 1
    pylint: django-not-available / Django is not available on the PYTHONPATH



Check Information
=================
         Started: 2019-11-18 17:57:27.136877
        Finished: 2019-11-18 17:57:27.301151
      Time Taken: 0.16 seconds
       Formatter: grouped
        Profiles: default, no_doc_warnings, no_test_warnings, strictness_medium, strictness_high, strictness_veryhigh, no_member_warnings
      Strictness: None
  Libraries Used: django, flask, celery
       Tools Run: dodgy, mccabe, pep8, profile-validator, pyflakes, pylint
  Messages Found: 1
```

Since [prospector issue 245](https://github.com/PyCQA/prospector/issues/245) and [pylint django PR 137](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django/pull/137/commits/bb41fd7dabe3a7dbec5b6c49da8fc38747cc4bad) Django became an extra dependency of pylint-django.

But running it without django installed still return a message:

```
$ pylint --load-plugins pylint_django src
************* Module src
src/__init__.py:1:0: C0111: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
src/__init__.py:1:0: F5101: Django is not available on the PYTHONPATH (django-not-available)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 0.00/10 (previous run: 0.00/10, +0.00)
```

My guess is prospector catch that message and return it when ran directly i.e with dependency automatic detection.

This seems like an bug/integration problem between the two libraries for me, but a confirmation from a contributor/maintainer from one the project is required.

Otherwise @Thaveedu a workaround is to disable the dependency automatic detection since in your case you probably don't care about django, flask or celery anyway:

```
$ prospector --no-autodetect src/
/home/sma/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/58918408_so/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pycodestyle.py:113: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
  EXTRANEOUS_WHITESPACE_REGEX = re.compile(r'[[({] | []}),;:]')
Check Information
=================
         Started: 2019-11-18 18:07:30.662236
        Finished: 2019-11-18 18:07:30.804708
      Time Taken: 0.14 seconds
       Formatter: grouped
        Profiles: default, no_doc_warnings, no_test_warnings, strictness_medium, strictness_high, strictness_veryhigh, no_member_warnings
      Strictness: None
  Libraries Used: 
       Tools Run: dodgy, mccabe, pep8, profile-validator, pyflakes, pylint
  Messages Found: 0
```

Comment: Thanks for reproducing them , One strange thing i have noticed is , this project is a new one while the older projects are working fine with the same `prospector` version

Comment: That's weird, are you sure it is the same `prospector` and `pylint-django` version and that you didn't install `django` directly with an older version of `pylint-django`?

Comment: This workaround worked with `--no-autodetect` flag, though I don't know how the older projects were working perfectly without this flag

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, [Propector supports Django, Celery and Flask](https://prospector.readthedocs.io/en/master/), which means it automatically installs the Pylint plugins needed for it to support these frameworks.

Is it possible you have specified to use pylint-django? In order for [pylint-django](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django) to inspect Django code it requires Django to be installed, prospector [docs](https://pypi.org/project/prospector/) states it doesn't normally automatically detect your project's dependencies, but it states you can turn them off using:

```
prospector --no-autodetect
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Uninstalling `pylint-django` gives an error `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pylint-django==2.0.10' distribution was not found and is required by prospector` and `pylint-django` only declare `django` as an extra. While trying to reproduce this I was able to run pylint without a problem but not prospector.

Comment: I'm investigating this more, https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/modules/pylint-django states pylint-django is a dependency for prospector. Let me change my answer.